# Have dll import symbols from its calling .exe

Tags: windows, dll, dllimport, dllexport

Related to but not equivalent to [DLL Get Symbols From Its Parent (Loader)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3752634/dll-get-symbols-from-its-parent-loader)

Is there a way to convince the Windows loader to resolve a particular symbol referenced by A.dll from either the loading executable or an intermediate dll without specifying the file to resolve symbols from in A.dll?

It's pretty obvious how to do it if the loading .exe has a known name, but if it isn't ...

Here's a good reason why you'd actually want to do this: https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Replacing-malloc.html

If this can be done, a good answer would say how to do it some way or another.

I'm half-expecting the answer is it can't be done. In that case, a good answer would show why this is impossible. "The build tools don't support this." is a bad answer.

Comment: if you use import - you need direct set PE name and function name. exactly. if you use delayload import or yourself got address of function - you can do anything

Comment: @RbMm: If you can write an answer involving delayload you can get cheap rep.

Comment: this is depended from what linker you use for build PE (dll in your case). in case *link.exe* you need yourself implement [`extern "C" LPCVOID WINAPI __delayLoadHelper2(PImgDelayDescr , PImgThunkData  )`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f0fkfy9y.aspx) where you can yourself implement any resolve symbol strategy

Comment: You mentioned *build tools*. Any specific one (*VStudio*, *MinGW*, ...)?

Comment: @CristiFati: I got a tools-agnostic answer from RbMm already, so there's no point constraining the question.

Comment: @Joshua AFAIK, the `__pfnDliNotifyHook2` method doesn't work with MinGW.

Comment: @ssbssa: But the GetProcAddress method does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when we use import we need exactly indicate module name and function name. and we can not use complex algorithms. also for *exe* not exist well known alias which we can use in place exactly exe name. for compare: in case get [`GetModuleHandle`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683199(v=vs.85).aspx) we can use `NULL` for get handle to the file used to create the calling process (.exe file). but in case [`LoadLibraryExW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-loadlibraryexw) we can not use 0 or empty string (`L""`) or some another alias for say - we want handle to *exe*. when loader load our module - he read dll name from `IMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR` and try found or load module with this name first by low level, private, core of [`LoadLibraryExW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-loadlibraryexw). here need exactly name. or load fail. as result use import - not a solution here, if we dont know exe name at build time

possible variant - resolve functions pointers yourself at runtime. here we can get exe `HMODULE` by `GetModuleHandle(0)`. also if need we can search function not only in *exe* but somewhere else. can implement any search algorithm.

here exist several ways. for concrete example let we need get pointer to function with signature:

```
void WINAPI fn(int i);
```

we can declare pointer to this function and resolve it in runtime

```
void (WINAPI *fn)(int);

*(void**)&fn = GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandleW(0), "fn");
```

say on `DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH`

a slightly different solution (although at the binary level it is completely equivalent) declare function with `__declspec(dllimport)` attribute. this is for *CL.EXE* (more known as *MSVC*) compiler only. so

```
__declspec(dllimport) void fn(int i);
```

in this case *CL* yourself generate pointer to function with name __imp_ ## [`__FUNCDNAME__`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/predefined-macros?view=vs-2017) name. so by fact the same as in first variant, when we declare pointer yourself. only difference in syntax and.. symbol name. it will be look like `__imp_?fn2@@YAXH@Z`. problem here that `__imp_?fn2@@YAXH@Z` not valid name for *c/c++* - we can not direct assign value to it from *c/c++*. even if we declare function with `extern "C"` - function name will be containing `@` symbol (illegal for *c++*) for `__stdcall` and `__fastcall` functions, for *x86*. also name will be different for different platforms (*x86*, *x64*, etc). for access such names - need or use external *asm* file (for asm `?` and `@` symbols valid in name) or use `/alternatename` linker option - for set alias for such name and access symbol via it. say like

```
__pragma(comment(linker, "/alternatename:__imp_?fn@@YAXH@Z=__imp_fn"))
```

and init via

```
*(void**)&__imp_fn = GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle(0), "fn");
```

another option use `__declspec(dllimport)` in function declarations + add import library, where all `__imp___FUNCDNAME__` (such `__imp_?fn2@@YAXH@Z`) is defined. (even if we have not such library we can easy create it yourself - all what need - correct function declarations with empty implementation). and after we add such import lib to linker input - add [`/DELAYLOAD:dllname`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/delayload-delay-load-import?view=vs-2017) where `dllname` - exactly name from import lib. sense that this `dllname` will(can) be not match to *exe* - all what need - it must be unique. and we need yourself handle delayload (called when we first time call `fn`). for implement delayload we need [implement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f0fkfy9y.aspx)

```
extern "C" FARPROC WINAPI __delayLoadHelper2(   
   PCImgDelayDescr pidd,  
   FARPROC * ppfnIATEntry  
);
```

we can implement it yourself, or add `delayimp.lib` to our project. here (in `delayimp.lib`) the `delayLoadHelper2` and implemented. however we must customize this process (default implementation(look in `/include/DelayHlp.cpp`) will be use `LoadLibraryExA` with `dllname` which is not excepted in our case - otherwise we can be simply use import as is). so we need mandatory implement `__pfnDliNotifyHook2`:

for example:

```
FARPROC WINAPI MyDliHook(
                             unsigned        dliNotify,
                             PDelayLoadInfo  pdli
                             )
{
    switch (dliNotify)
    {
    case dliNotePreLoadLibrary:
        if (!strcmp(pdli->szDll, "unique_exe_alias"))
        {
            return (FARPROC)GetModuleHandle(0);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

const PfnDliHook  __pfnDliNotifyHook2 = MyDliHook;
```

we can look for `dliNotePreLoadLibrary` notification and instead default `LoadLibraryEx(dli.szDll, NULL, 0);` use `GetModuleHandle(0);` for get base of *exe*.
the "unique_exe_alias" (which linker got from import library) here play role not real *exe* name, which is unknown, but unique tag(alias) for exe

Comment: I have a problem linking with imported symbols of `node.exe` when building a node-api addon with MinGW. Your answer was very useful - it gave an idea of a workaround. But I still cannot link implicitly. Could you maybe look into https://stackoverflow.com/q/67648225/9363996 ?