# Node js (node-api) addon compiled with MinGW causes access violation

Tags: c++, node.js, dll, access-violation

### Building node-api linked native addon

I am out of thoughts on the cause of the problem after 3 days of investigating and researching.
Basically I am loading a hello world Node JS addon compiled with MinGW64 and linked against C node-api.

The code is as follows:

```
// hello.c

#include <node/node_api.h>

napi_value Method(napi_env env, napi_callback_info args)
{
    napi_value greeting;
    napi_status status = napi_create_string_utf8(env, "hello, asshole", NAPI_AUTO_LENGTH, &greeting);

    return status == napi_ok ? greeting : (napi_value)0;
}

napi_value init(napi_env env, napi_value exports)
{
    napi_value function;

    napi_status status = napi_create_function(env, 0, 0, &Method, 0, &function);
    if (status != napi_ok)
        return (napi_value)0;

    status = napi_set_named_property(env, exports, "hello", function);
    return status == napi_ok ? exports : (napi_value)0;
}

// static void _register_hello(void)__attribute((constructor));
// calls napi_module_register
NAPI_MODULE(hello, init)
```

I have downloaded dist headers and precompiled `node.lib` which I link against. This is my `CMakeLists.txt` file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.11.4 FATAL_ERROR)

project(hello-node-api LANGUAGES C CXX)

add_library(hello SHARED hello.c)

# TODO: download dist and make an imported target
target_include_directories(hello PRIVATE node-v16.2.0/include)
target_link_libraries(hello PRIVATE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/node-v16.2.0/node.lib)

set_target_properties(hello PROPERTIES
        SUFFIX ".node"
        PREFIX ""
        )

target_compile_definitions(hello PUBLIC BUILDING_NODE_EXTENSION)
```

### Some explanation on the addon loading [routine](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/6cb314bbe5ee5c9af3c111516fb7f7689c10ecda/src/node_binding.cc#L445):

Node.exe is compiled with exported symbols, that are provided within the `node.lib`.
Node.exe loads an addon and a dll entry point (on Windows it is `__DllMainCRTStart`) is called.
Either of the dll versions (compiled either with MSVC or MinGW) are loaded just fine: the entry point is called, and all the user-defined functions are callable without errors. But an attempt to invoke an imported `napi_` function results in access violation with MinGW.

```
Exception thrown at 0x0000000000009238 in node.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation executing location 0x0000000000009238.
```

With MSVC api functions are entered normally and the addon gets registered etc.

### Analog dummy MSVC c++ exe that loads a MinGW addon that links to exported C MSVC symbols from exe:

First I thought that the problem is caused by the compiler, but a dummy exe(MSVC)->addon(MinGW)->exe_symbols(MSVC) works just fine regardless of the compiler used to build an exe: `extern "C"` is used to export symbols:

Export header:

```
// esport.h

#pragma once

#ifndef BUILDING
#define EXPORT_API __declspec(dllimport)
#else
#define EXPORT_API __declspec(dllexport)
#endif

EXPORT_API void hello_addon();
EXPORT_API int sum(int a, int b);
```

Addon:

```
// addon.c
#include <export.h>

static void print_hello_from_export(void)__attribute((constructor));

void print_hello_from_export(void)
{
    int res = sum(4, 15);
    hello_addon();
}
```

exe:

```
extern "C" {
#include "export.h"
}

#include <iostream>

void hello_addon()
{
    std::cout << "hello addon" << std::endl;
}

int sum(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}

#include <windows.h>

int main()
{
    HMODULE handle = LoadLibraryA("addon.dll");
    return 0;
}
```

So, the library is loaded and a message is printed, regardless of the compiler used to build the executable. This behavior is expected when using the C ABI.

### Back to the problem with node-api

I tried to look through the symbols within the `hello.node` binary but I don't know what to do with this info.

```
...
[894](sec  1)(fl 0x00)(ty   0)(scl   2) (nx 0) 0x0000000000001410 __CTOR_LIST__
[895](sec  8)(fl 0x00)(ty   0)(scl   2) (nx 0) 0x0000000000000014 _head_lib64_libkernel32_a
[896](sec  8)(fl 0x00)(ty   0)(scl   2) (nx 0) 0x0000000000000150 __imp_napi_module_register
...
```

Here is the Ninja script generated by cmake:
MSVC build

```
build CMakeFiles\hello.dir\hello.c.obj: C_COMPILER__hello_Debug C$:\dev\repos\hello-node-api\hello.c || cmake_object_order_depends_target_hello
  DEFINES = -DBUILDING_NODE_EXTENSION -Dhello_EXPORTS
  FLAGS = /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3 /MDd /Zi /Ob0 /Od /RTC1
  INCLUDES = -IC:\dev\repos\hello-node-api\node-v16.2.0\include
  OBJECT_DIR = CMakeFiles\hello.dir
  OBJECT_FILE_DIR = CMakeFiles\hello.dir
  TARGET_COMPILE_PDB = CMakeFiles\hello.dir\
  TARGET_PDB = hello.pdb


# =============================================================================
# Link build statements for SHARED_LIBRARY target hello


#############################################
# Link the shared library hello.node

build hello.node hello.lib: C_SHARED_LIBRARY_LINKER__hello_Debug CMakeFiles\hello.dir\hello.c.obj | C$:\dev\repos\hello-node-api\node-v16.2.0\node.lib
  LANGUAGE_COMPILE_FLAGS = /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3 /MDd /Zi /Ob0 /Od /RTC1
  LINK_FLAGS = /machine:x64 /debug /INCREMENTAL
  LINK_LIBRARIES = C:\dev\repos\hello-node-api\node-v16.2.0\node.lib  kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib
  OBJECT_DIR = CMakeFiles\hello.dir
  POST_BUILD = cd .
  PRE_LINK = cd .
  RESTAT = 1
  TARGET_COMPILE_PDB = CMakeFiles\hello.dir\
  TARGET_FILE = hello.node
  TARGET_IMPLIB = hello.lib
  TARGET_PDB = hello.pdb
```

MinGW build

```
#############################################
# Order-only phony target for hello

build cmake_object_order_depends_target_hello: phony || CMakeFiles/hello.dir

build CMakeFiles/hello.dir/hello.c.obj: C_COMPILER__hello_Debug C$:/dev/repos/hello-node-api/hello.c || cmake_object_order_depends_target_hello
  DEFINES = -DBUILDING_NODE_EXTENSION -Dhello_EXPORTS
  DEP_FILE = CMakeFiles\hello.dir\hello.c.obj.d
  FLAGS = -g
  INCLUDES = -IC:/dev/repos/hello-node-api/node-v16.2.0/include
  OBJECT_DIR = CMakeFiles\hello.dir
  OBJECT_FILE_DIR = CMakeFiles\hello.dir


# =============================================================================
# Link build statements for SHARED_LIBRARY target hello


#############################################
# Link the shared library hello.node

build hello.node libhello.dll.a: C_SHARED_LIBRARY_LINKER__hello_Debug CMakeFiles/hello.dir/hello.c.obj | C$:/dev/repos/hello-node-api/node-v16.2.0/node.lib
  LANGUAGE_COMPILE_FLAGS = -g
  LINK_LIBRARIES = C:/dev/repos/hello-node-api/node-v16.2.0/node.lib  -lkernel32 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lwinspool -lshell32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -luuid -lcomdlg32 -ladvapi32
  OBJECT_DIR = CMakeFiles\hello.dir
  POST_BUILD = cd .
  PRE_LINK = cd .
  RESTAT = 1
  TARGET_FILE = hello.node
  TARGET_IMPLIB = libhello.dll.a
  TARGET_PDB = hello.node.dbg
```

I can't spot any significant differences in compilation and linking.

I also noticed that visual studio project generated to build Node has a distinct target to build `node.lib`. I don't know if it matters, but here is the command line args from `.vsproj`

```
/Yu"node_pch.h" /MP /GS /W3 /wd"4351" /wd"4355" /wd"4800" /wd"4251" /wd"4275" /wd"4267" /Zc:wchar_t /I"src" /I"out\Debug\obj\global_intermediate" /I"out\Debug\obj\global_intermediate\include" /I"out\Debug\obj\global_intermediate\src" /I"tools\msvs\genfiles" /I"deps\histogram\src" /I"deps\uvwasi\include" /I"deps\v8\include" /I"deps\icu-small\source\i18n" /I"deps\icu-small\source\common" /I"deps\zlib" /I"deps\llhttp\include" /I"deps\cares\include" /I"deps\uv\include" /I"deps\nghttp2\lib\includes" /I"deps\brotli\c\include" /I"deps\openssl\openssl\include" /I"deps\ngtcp2" /I"deps\ngtcp2\ngtcp2\lib\includes" /I"deps\ngtcp2\ngtcp2\crypto\includes" /I"deps\ngtcp2\nghttp3\lib\includes" /Z7 /Gm- /Od /Fd"out\Debug\obj\libnode\libnode.pdb" /FI"node_pch.h" /Zc:inline /fp:precise /D "V8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS" /D "V8_IMMINENT_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS" /D "_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1" /D "WIN32" /D "_CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE" /D "_CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE" /D "_HAS_EXCEPTIONS=0" /D "BUILDING_V8_SHARED=1" /D "BUILDING_UV_SHARED=1" /D "OPENSSL_NO_PINSHARED" /D "OPENSSL_THREADS" /D "OPENSSL_NO_ASM" /D "NODE_ARCH=\"x64\"" /D "NODE_WANT_INTERNALS=1" /D "V8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1" /D "NODE_OPENSSL_SYSTEM_CERT_PATH=\"\"" /D "HAVE_INSPECTOR=1" /D "HAVE_ETW=1" /D "FD_SETSIZE=1024" /D "NODE_PLATFORM=\"win32\"" /D "NOMINMAX" /D "_UNICODE=1" /D "NODE_USE_V8_PLATFORM=1" /D "NODE_HAVE_I18N_SUPPORT=1" /D "HAVE_OPENSSL=1" /D "UCONFIG_NO_SERVICE=1" /D "U_ENABLE_DYLOAD=0" /D "U_STATIC_IMPLEMENTATION=1" /D "U_HAVE_STD_STRING=1" /D "UCONFIG_NO_BREAK_ITERATION=0" /D "NGHTTP2_STATICLIB" /D "NGTCP2_STATICLIB" /D "NGHTTP3_STATICLIB" /D "DEBUG" /D "_DEBUG" /D "V8_ENABLE_CHECKS" /errorReport:prompt /GF /WX- /Zc:forScope /RTC1 /Gd /Oy- /MTd /FC /Fa"out\Debug\obj\libnode\" /nologo /Fo"out\Debug\obj\libnode\" /Fp"out\Debug\obj\libnode\libnode.pch" /diagnostics:column
```

I am out of ideas, on the web there are some fruitless attempts to load a mingw-compiled addon. Some of them are from several years ago and still no result. So I ask the community for help in order to solve this issue or at least understand why it can't be solved.

So it boils down to:

1. What causes the access violation? Is it because of the imported symbol address is not within the address space (how can I check it?), or maybe the address of the symbol that was used during linking does not correspond to the address within the `node.exe`?
2. If the problem can't be solved on behalf of the addon, what might be the problem in Node compilation?

---

### Checking function addresses:

I decided to look into the possibility that the loaded (who exactly loads it? Is it `__DllMainRTCStartup`?) addresses differ from the addresses within the `node.exe`

While inside the `node.exe`:
`0x00007ff629d198e0 {node.exe!napi_module_register(napi_module *)}`

Disassembly:

```
// Registers a NAPI module.
void napi_module_register(napi_module* mod) {
00007FF629D198E0  mov         qword ptr [rsp+8],rcx  
00007FF629D198E5  push        rsi  
00007FF629D198E6  push        rdi  
00007FF629D198E7  sub         rsp,0C8h  
00007FF629D198EE  mov         rdi,rsp  
00007FF629D198F1  mov         ecx,32h  
00007FF629D198F6  mov         eax,0CCCCCCCCh  
00007FF629D198FB  rep stos    dword ptr [rdi]  
00007FF629D198FD  mov         rcx,qword ptr [mod]   
...
```

But when inside the `hello.node`:
`identifier "napi_module_register" is undefined` - I don't know if it is expected.
Disassembly:

```
static void _register_hello(void) __attribute((constructor));
static void _register_hello(void)
{
00007FFC02F81479  push        rbp  
00007FFC02F8147A  mov         rbp,rsp  
00007FFC02F8147D  sub         rsp,20h  
    napi_module_register(&_module);
00007FFC02F81481  lea         rcx,[7FFC02F83020h]  
00007FFC02F81488  mov         rax,qword ptr [7FFC02F89150h]  
00007FFC02F8148F  call        rax  
}
00007FFC02F81491  nop  
00007FFC02F81492  add         rsp,20h  
00007FFC02F81496  pop         rbp  
00007FFC02F81497  ret
```

`call rax` leads to `0000000000009238  ?? ??????`  and then access violation is thrown.

---

It looks like the import table for `node.exe` is empty:

```
There is an import table in .idata at 0xb32a9000

The Import Tables (interpreted .idata section contents)
 vma:            Hint    Time      Forward  DLL       First
                 Table   Stamp     Chain    Name      Thunk
 00009000   00009084 00000000 00000000 000092a0 00009170

    DLL Name: node.exe
    vma:  Hint/Ord Member-Name Bound-To
```

And for dll compiled with MSVC it is *NOT EMPTY*:

```
Dump of file .\hello.node

File Type: DLL

  Section contains the following imports:

    node.exe
             18000E1F8 Import Address Table
             18000E5E8 Import Name Table
                     0 time date stamp
                     0 Index of first forwarder reference

                        6707 napi_set_named_property
                        66A4 napi_create_function
                        66F3 napi_module_register
                        66AD napi_create_string_utf8
```

Looks like it mught be the reasin after all.

**Can an empty import address table be the reason?**

Comment: So, you compiled addon with MinGW manually? I mean, you didn't use node-gyp? Because it seems, that node-gyp don't support MinGW and I am wondered how and why you compile with MinGW.

Comment: @van9petryk for pure C symbols it doesn't matter what compiler you use, because C++ runtime is not involved. This is quiet an old question, and I don't know if they have fixed Mingw binutils. The problem was with a faulty behavior of MinGW linker - it couldn't properly import a symbol table if it contained C++ mangled sybols alonside with C symbols. A working solution was to create an import library from node.lib containing only C symbols.

Answer (score 2):

I believe your problem is this:

```
LINK_LIBRARIES = C:/dev/repos/hello-node-api/node-v16.2.0/node.lib
```

node.lib is an MSVC library, which will not work with mingw.

You need to create a .def file (it's a text file with napi symbols):

```
LIBRARY node.exe
EXPORTS
napi_set_named_property
napi_create_function
etc
```

The list of exports per napi version are in this repo: https://github.com/nodejs/node-api-headers

Finally, use mingw's dlltool to turn the .def to a .a (static lib). Link that lib file with you mingw program.

Comment: Thank you for yor answer. The question has been discussed on github and there's an answer in the thread https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/38782 I'd like to point out, that `will not work with mingw` may not be accurate. The problem was caused by mangled symbols within the import library. If I remember correctly (was long time ago), msvc-built import library with only C symbols can be linked just fine with mingw.

Answer (score 1):

This is a legit workaround, that provides some "temporary" solution. It involves explicit loading of symbols from the calling application, which has to be `node.exe`.

Though it does work, I am still looking for a *conventional* solution to correctly load imported symbols implicitly.

```
#include <node/node_api.h>

#include <windows.h>

static void (*pRegisterModule)(napi_module*);
static napi_status (*pCreateStringUtf8)(napi_env, const char*, size_t, napi_value *);
static napi_status (*pCreateFunction)(napi_env, const char*, size_t, napi_callback, void*, napi_value*);
static napi_status (*pSetNamedProperty)(napi_env, napi_value, const char*, napi_value);

napi_value Method(napi_env env, napi_callback_info args)
{
    napi_value greeting;
    napi_status status = // napi_create_string_utf8(env, "hello workaround", NAPI_AUTO_LENGTH, &greeting);
            pCreateStringUtf8(env, "hello workaround", NAPI_AUTO_LENGTH, &greeting);

    return status == napi_ok ? greeting : (napi_value)0;
}

napi_value init(napi_env env, napi_value exports)
{
    napi_value function;

    napi_status status = // napi_create_function(env, 0, 0, &Method, 0, &function);
            pCreateFunction(env, 0, 0, &Method, 0, &function);

    if (status != napi_ok)
        return (napi_value)0;

    status = // napi_set_named_property(env, exports, "hello", function);
            pSetNamedProperty(env, exports, "hello", function);
    return status == napi_ok ? exports : (napi_value)0;
}

// static void _register_hello(void)__attribute((constructor));
// calls napi_module_register
//NAPI_MODULE(hello, init)
static napi_module _module = {NAPI_MODULE_VERSION,
                           0,
                           __FILE__,
                           init,
                           "hello",
                           (void*)0,
                           {0}};

typedef void(WINAPI *void_func_ptr_t)(void);

static void _register_hello(void) __attribute((constructor));
static void _register_hello(void)
{
    // TODO: load pointers from calling exe
    *(void**)&pRegisterModule = GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandleW(0),
                                  "napi_module_register");
    *(void**)&pCreateStringUtf8 = GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandleW(0),
                                                 "napi_create_string_utf8");
    *(void**)&pCreateFunction = GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandleW(0),
                                                 "napi_create_function");
    *(void**)&pSetNamedProperty = GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandleW(0),
                                               "napi_set_named_property");

    pRegisterModule(&_module);
//    napi_module_register(&_module);
}
```