# DLL with no compiled dependencies

Tags: c, gcc, mingw, unresolved-external

I am trying to compile a DLL with mingw32 (x86_64-w64-wingw32-gcc) in the smallest way possible.

I have an executable client running that has all of the dependencies that the DLL would need, like json.c and base64.c.

Instead of compiling json.c and base64.c into the DLL, I would rather find a way to ignore the "undefined reference" errors and let the DLL pull functions from the executable client's json.c and base64.c.

***Thus, my question. How do I compile this zero-dependency DLL using mingw?***

I've tried `-Wl,--unresolved-symbols=ignore-all` but it doesn't work. The option is valid... but the GCC error output is the same.

Here, I have an exectuable running with `printSuccess` function defined and I am trying to compile this DLL to have an unresolved symbol that will be called with `__declspec(dllimport)` when the DLL does `DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH` that should (hopefully) launch `printSuccess` once I `LoadLibrary & GetProcAddress`.

This is the output:

```
dev@CLIENT2:/$ x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc main.c -Wl,--unresolved-symbols=ignore-all -o main64.exe

main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:10:2: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘printSuccess’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   10 |  printSuccess();
      |  ^~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: /tmp/cctVzHaX.o:main.c:(.text+0x15): undefined reference to `printSuccess'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: In Windows, a DLL can import symbols from the EXE that loads the DLL, but the EXE will have to have an export table which is somewhat unusual.  Are you able to make changes to the EXE?

Comment: Where is your code? Did you forget to declare your functions as `__declspec(dllimport)`?

Comment: I can make changes to the EXE, yes. But, even if I make an export table in the EXE, I still don't know how to compile the DLL to take advantage of that.

Comment: First, please add `@username` to your comments when replying, otherwise we don't get notifications.

Comment: When you build the EXE with exports, you'll get an import library created (just like with a DLL).  You'll pass that import library to the DLL build process.  That will eliminate the unresolved externals (because the linker will create an import table in the DLL, that matches up against the export table in the EXE).

Comment: Second, `implicit declaration of function` indicates that you did not declare the function as `__declspec(dllimport)` (didn't declare it at all, in fact).

Comment: Warning that circular imports will make it impossible to directly build the whole project from nothing.  You'll have to have skeleton/placeholder code to build the import libraries, so that you can use them to link the real code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3752634/103167

Comment: @BenVoigt - wow. Yes, making an EXE with exports and importing the library to the DLL during build sounds like the perfect course-of-action. Thank you for the link. I'm not 100% sure how to go about it but that is the best idea I've heard so far.

Answer (score -1):

Well because compiler needs the functions to be present when linking, because the addresses have to be looked up, what you are trying to do is impossible.

My recommendation is to actually move the json and base to different module, which then can be depended on by executable and the other DLL.

Comment: The linker needs an import library, then the functions won't be present during link time -- the addresses will be matched up by the loader.  That's how an EXE consumes functions from a DLL... and it *can* be done to consume functions from an EXE too.

Comment: I'm not against a "CommonDependencies.dll" either. Honestly, I might actually prefer it, @BenVoigt. Assuming that this is a good gameplan, how would I proceed? I would compile CommonDeps.dll with the required `dllexports` and have the EXE (and subsequent Module DLLs) compile with the required `dllimports` then, once I do a LoadLibrary(CommonDeps.dll), then everything should magically link up? I can then create and read json strings?

Comment: @Stryker2k2: The import table will name `CommonDeps.dll` and the loader will load it automatically... no `LoadLibrary()` or `GetProcAddress()` call necessary.  Having a common DLL which both EXE and other DLL use is definitely the more common approach, and recommended because it avoids circular imports.